# Created nano file raspberry pi: Crontab

Tags: raspbian

I am using  nano 2.7.4 and have created a file to receive sensor data to table in SQL. I'm able to run the task form the command line and receive the correct data back in the database. However, the program will not run on its own.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think something got lost during posting the question, i.e. that script. Does the crontab contain any uncommented lines?

Comment: ... also the last line in the crontab is duplicated

Comment: I checked that and it's not in the file. Must have been when I copied it. Sorry.

Comment: No, it didn't copy right. All lines include #.

Comment: what you can do is check the cron log files for any errors

Answer (score 2):

As @Ghanima has said, you must first remove the comment character (#) in the line that you wish to execute (and probably the leading `/`). But you may also need to make another change before that command in your `crontab` will execute: you will need to indicate how you want your Python script executed. So, your revised line will look like this:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/tempLog/readTempSQL.py
```

I have assumed that your script runs under Python 3. If instead you wish to use Python 2, change the python path accordingly.

`cron` does not have the same $PATH as you do from your [login shell](http://www.learnlinux.org.za/courses/build/shell-scripting/ch02s02.html), and so you must provide the PATH information to `cron`. One other thing that might help is to redirect any `stderr` output (errors) to a file as this may be useful in debugging any issues that occur. If you wish to do this:

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/tempLog/readTempSQL.py  > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81879/discussion-on-answer-by-seamus-created-nano-file-raspberry-pi-crontab). I understand that you and the OP are using the comments to solve the problem but I hope that a chatroom will work too. Feel free to update your answer - and the OP the question, respectively - with any new input nonetheless. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your crontab contains only commented lines... include at least one line without the `#`, likely that last line, which should read:

```
/10 * * * * /home/pi/tempLog/readTempSQL.py
```

instead of

```
#/10 * * * * /home/pi/tempLog/readTempSQL.py
```

Sidenote:

Per [this page](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) mind that:

> Repeat pattern like /2 for every 2 minutes or /10 for every 10 minutes is not supported by all operating systems. If you try to use it and crontab complains it is probably not supported.

Sidenote 2:

The shebang of your script should have another slash

```
#!/usr/bin/env
```

instead of

```
#! usr/bin/env
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will remove the the "/"? Would "* * * * *" mean every minute?

Comment: @00BEAR I would give that repeat pattern a try, the site does not claim that it *will not* work, only that it *might not* work on certain systems. Crontab will complain if it does not.

Comment: Ok, no problem with "/", I still receive back the data, but only if I run it. I'm using ~$ sudo chmod +x readTempSQL.py to execute? I this ok?

Comment: Have you tried [Seamus'](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88225/19949) advice? Redirecting error output (which otherwise would be discarded by cron) could give useful hints, provided the script generates helpful error messages. `chmod` does not execute a file, it changes the permission so that it becomes executable. Either way (+x or not) you can always run it the way that Seamus' answer suggests by calling the Python interpreter and handing over the scripts name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hash at the start of the line. Hash is used to comment out a line.

Add *python* after the * and before the address path.

Add & after the address path to allow background tasks.

Comment: Such as this? 10 * * * *  python /usr/bin/python3 & /home/pi/tempLog/readTempSQL.py  > /home/pi/cronjob$

Comment: no, the `&` would go at the end of a command line, not half way in the middle

Comment: 10 * * * *  python  /home/pi/tempLog/readTempSQL.py  > /home/pi/cronjob$ &

Comment: There is no need for the ampersand with cron, despite it being a myth repeatedly told on Stackexchange and all over the internet.